# Applets, embedding and the bokeh-server

Tags: python, bokeh

There seem to be at at least **two or three major ways** of building **apps** that communicate with `bokeh-server` in Bokeh. They correspond to the [folders](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples) [`app`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app), [`embed`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed) and [`plotting`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/plotting)/[`glyphs`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/glyphs) under the [examples](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples) directory in Bokeh.

On the differences between them, I read [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/bokeh/NClF-837DMc/hCfy8tnyFDUJ) the following:

> On the [`stock_app.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stock_applet/stock_app.py) ([`app`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app) folder) example you are using `bokeh-server` to **embed an
>   applet** and serve it from the url you specify. That's why you crate a
>   new `StockApp` class and create a function that creates a new instance
>   of it and decorates it with @`bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/stocks/")` and
>   `@object_page("stocks")`. You can follow the **[`app`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app) examples** (sliders,
>   stock and crossfilter) and use bokeh `@object_page` and `@bokeh_app.route`
>   decorators to create your custom url.
>
> On the [`taylor_server.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/glyphs/taylor_server.py) example ([`glyphs`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/glyphs) folder) it is the **session object** that
>   is taking care of creating everything on `bokeh-server` for you. From
>   this interface is not possible to customize urls or create alias.

But this confused me, what is meant by an "applet" & "embedding" in Bokeh terminology, and what is
**exactly** he difference between applets (presumably [`app`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app) and [`embed`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed)) and [`plotting`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/plotting)/[`glyphs`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/glyphs)?

Also I thought that the notion of "embedding" only referred to the design pattern that we see in the `embed` folder as in the example  [`animated.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/animated.py), where we embed a `tag` in the body of an HTML file. I don't see that in the [`stock_app.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stock_applet/stock_app.py), so why is it an embedding example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this confused me, what is meant by an "applet" & "embedding" in
>   Bokeh terminology

There is clearly a mistake in the answer you have pasted here (that probably doesn't help you on understanding, sorry). The stock app example  `stock_app.py` is in examples\app\stock_applet\stock_app.py not embed folder. Also, the terminology used does not help either. On that example you create an applet that can be served in 2 different ways:

1. running directly on a bokeh-server
2. embedded (or integrated if you prefer) into a separate application (a Flask application in that case)

You may find more information at the `examples\app\stock_applet\README.md` file.

Also, you can find info about applets and bokeh server [examples documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/examples.html#id2) and [userguide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/server.html)

Regarding what does embedding means, you can find more info at the user_guide/embedding section of bokeh docs. To summarize, you can generate code that you can insert on your own web application code to display bokeh components. Examples in examples\embed are also useful to understand this pattern.

Finally, the usage of bokeh-server you see in `taylor_server.py` is just using bokeh server to serve you plot (instead of saving it to a static html file).

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabio. This is very helpful and clear now. My mistake on the directory of the `stock_app.py` (I just updated that on the OP).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little bit... I will paste here a quote from Bryan in the mailing list (in another thread, so maybe you missed it):

> Regarding app vs embed. The "apps" are all run *inside* the bokeh-server. So you start them,
>   by doing something like:
>
> ```
>     bokeh-server --script sliders_app.py
> ```
>
> The main reason for this is because, otherwise, to make an "app"
>   outside the server, the only real solutions is to have a long-running
>   process that polls the server for updates. This is not ideal, and apps
>   running directly in the server can utilize much better callbacks. 
>   Please note that the "app" concept is still fairly new, and things
>   like how to start, easily spell, and deploy apps is very much open to
>   improvement.
>
> The "embed" examples simply show off how to embed a Bokeh plot in a
>   standard web-app (i.e., you want to serve a plot from Flask that has a
>   plot in it). This can be done with, or without the bokeh-server, but
>   even if you use a bokeh-server, there is no code running *in the
>   bokeh-server* that responds to widgets, or updates plots or data. To
>   update plots you'd have to have a separate python process that
>   connects to the bokeh-server and polls or pushes data to it.

Cheers.

Damian